# java.io.IOException: No X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port (jenkins cli not working )

Tags: java, exception, jenkins, http-status-code-403, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to run the following command:

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins_URL/ --username myusername --password mypassword help`

But I'm getting the error :

> java.io.IOException: No X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port among [null, X-Required-Permission, X-Jenkins, X-You-Are-In-Group, X-Hudson, Content-Length, Expires, X-You-Are-Authenticated-As, X-Permission-Implied-By, Set-Cookie, Server, X-Content-Type-Options, Date, X-Jenkins-Session, Content-Type]
>       at hudson.cli.CLI.getCliTcpPort(CLI.java:284)
>       at hudson.cli.CLI.(CLI.java:128)
>       at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:72)
>       at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:473)
>       at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:384)
>       Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://52.9.217.252:8888/cli
>           at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1628)
>           at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:78)
>           at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:152)
>           at hudson.cli.CLI.(CLI.java:132)
>           ... 3 more

my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>false</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
  </securityRealm>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
  <workspaceDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
  <jdks/>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
  <clouds/>
  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
  <views>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>All</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <primaryView>All</primaryView>
  <slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>
  <label></label>
  <crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
    <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
  </crumbIssuer>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <globalNodeProperties/>
</hudson>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an official solution at the [Jenkins Wiki Page for CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).

The **solution** is

- Go to **Manage Jenkins** (in the Jenkins UI)
- -> **Configure Global Security**
- -> "TCP port for JNLP agents": choose fixed or random

Answer (score 2):

For those looking on how to make this work programatically (unattended).
You have to change

```
    <jenkins.CLI>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </jenkins.CLI>
```

to

```
    <jenkins.CLI>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </jenkins.CLI>
```

in /var/lib/jenkins/jenkins.CLI.xml and restart jenkins

Comment: That will allow the -remoting option without enabling security, not changing anything manually.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure it's not an username and/or password error change this line:

```
<denyAnonymousReadAccess>true</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
```

into:

```
<denyAnonymousReadAccess>false</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
```

in your config.xml file.

Now you can connect to your jenkins interface to debug your credentials

Don't forget to reset it to true.

Comment: I'm able to see the jenkins interface. I'm not able to run the CLI commands. I tried doing what you said, I'm still not able to run the CLI commands/

Comment: You have a 403 error, if it's not a credential issue, maybe it's about your web server config. Can you put your web server config? With more informations (port, proxy port etc...)

Comment: I've added my config.xml to the description.

Comment: Can you put your jenkins web server config? (apache or nginx etc...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to understand...why would I install an apache or nginx  server?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not clear why it fails, run under `strace`/`dtruss` debugger, e.g.

```
$ strace -fs1000 -e trace=network java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ help
```

If you've got:

> HTTP/1.1 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

error, then you need to either provide crumb in the request, or disable [CSRF Protection](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection).

Using Jenkins CLI [it's not working yet](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18114) when the crumb issuer is enabled, so you can use `curl` instead. For example (replace `localhost` with your Jenkins address):

1. Note your user API Token (`/user/USER/configure`).
2. Get your crumb:

   ```
   CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
   ```
3. Invoke some command (e.g. list the jobs):

   ```
   curl -H $CRUMB http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/api/json
   ```

Related: [Jenkins REST API Create job](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38137760/55075)