# Jenkins REST API Create job

Tags: jenkins

I'm creating a new job in Jenkins using the REST API. I tried the below curl command lines, but they are throwing an error

```
curl -i -X POST --user "admin:<API token>" --data-binary "@C:\mylocalconfig.xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=NewJob

curl -X POST -u <username>:<pass> -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -d "@C:\mylocalconfig.xml" "http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=AA_TEST_JOB3"
```

Error:

---

```
HTTP/1.1 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 05:25:59 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Length: 360
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /createItem. Reason:
<pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><i><small>Power
ed by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 82):

Jenkins by default has [CSRF Protection](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-CSRFProtection) enabled which prevents [one-click attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). To invoke the request, you need to obtain the crumb from `/crumbIssuer/api/xml` using your credentials and include it into your request.

For example:

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

Then you can create a job (by including the crumb into your header):

```
curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" "http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/createItem?name=NewJob"
```

<sup>If the above won't work, check your crumb (`echo $CRUMB`) or run `curl` with `-u USER:TOKEN`.</sup>

For a more detailed explanation, see: *[Running jenkins jobs via command line](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jnrg/running-jenkins-build-via-command-line)*.

Comment: When I do this, I get
'Error

No Content-Type header set'

Comment: As of 2017, this is the full example: [Running jenkins jobs via command line](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jnrg/running-jenkins-build-via-command-line)

Comment: How to get the json format response when createItem?it always return html

Comment: In case you want to replace CURL with Python requests library - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72858859/7991646

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Postman to fire the requests, using @kenorb example above, get the crumb
[image]

**To create a folder at root level using the createItem endpoint**
[image]

**To create a sub-folder inside the folder created above using the createItem endpoint**
[image]