# How to install Jenkins plugins through PluginManager API REST

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

After getting the crumb ID and store it in a variable, I try to launch the following command:

```
curl -X POST -d '<jenkins><install plugin="git@latest" /></jenkins>' --header 'Content-Type: text/xml' 'admin:'${INIT_PASS}'@127.0.0.1:8080/pluginManager/installNecessaryPlugins'
```

The following header is returned in response:

> Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request

The problem is that I don't know how to pass this argument, the crumb, in this kind of request, I've researched a lot of forums and documentation but seems not so much information.

Checking this in Jenkins v2.32.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins REST API Create job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137760/jenkins-rest-api-create-job)

Answer (score 1):

Add -u option in your curl command with `-u username:token` Note: you need to use **token** instead of **password**. You can generate token in user configure
[image: user config]

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314369.
You can disable CSRF protection(not preferred) or generate CRUMB.