# Jenkins "Trigger builds remotely" > "Authentication Token" option missing

Tags: jenkins

I have just been working on setting up Jenkins (latest - 2.5) behind a reverse proxy with Nginx so that I can access it over HTTPS.

It's working, however my Multibranch Pipeline jobs no longer have the "Trigger Builds Remotely" option in the main config. I don't think I changed any other configurations. Any ideas what happened and how to get it back?

Here's what I want back:

[image: Screenshot of what I want back]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After some time and searching around, I think I am able to answer my own question with some confidence.

I believe the answer lies within the security settings. The purpose of the Authentication Token is to allow unauthorized users (developers) to trigger a build without having login access to Jenkins (see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security).

So if you are using Matrix-based security (under "Configure Global Security" >> Authorization), then the "Trigger builds remotely" option will go away because it is presumed that you will be authenticating requests using a Jenkins user account.

In order to do that you can make an HTTP request with the username/password (or even better username/API Token):

```
curl -X POST "https://username:api-token@JENKINS_URL/job/Example/build"
```

Comment: are those quotes around the jenkins url on purpose? This is not working for me.

Comment: @val's post below worked for me, I removed the quotes and added -I.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I also assumed that I need the auth token.

Answer (score 28):

## Disclaimer

> Before reading this answer you have to know that I just accumulate all helpful information in this answer, which I've found across stackoverflow, all creds should be for guys who did actual researches.

I move the content of the link from this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137760/jenkins-rest-api-create-job#comment75710125_38314369) to stackoverflow just to preserve from deadlink.

## Info

The name of my job is `Football`. I would also suggest you to create a dedicated jenkins user and password rather than using `admin:admin` as I'll use in this example. My jenkins GUI URL is `http://192.168.99.20:8080` as I am on vagrant.

## Create job

1. Login to jenkins in `http://192.168.99.20:8080` address.
2. Create a "Free Style" project named as "Football".
3. Open it's configuration.
4. Go to "Build Triggers" section.
5. Tick "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" option just to take a note of the text written in there and untick it again. Text reads `Use the following URL to trigger build remotely: JENKINS_URL/job/Football/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME. Optionally append &cause=Cause+Text to provide text that will be included in the recorded build cause..`
6. Save and exit.

## Get API user and token

1. Login to jenkins in `http://192.168.99.20:8080` address.
2. Click your username (mine is admin) on right hand side of the page.
3. Select "Configure" option which will take you to `http://192.168.99.20:8080/user/admin/configure` page.
4. In "API Token" section click "Show API token" button.
5. Note "User ID" and "API Token" to use in your curl command later on. e.g. `admin:85703fb68927f04968630e192e4927cb`

## Obtain crumb

For more information, visit Remote access API page.

```
$ wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user admin --password admin --output-document - 'http://192.168.99.20:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'
```

This will give you something like `Jenkins-Crumb:44e7033af70da95a47403c3bed5c10f8`. Without crumb information, running curl command will result in example errors such as `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` or `Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request`.

## Test

```
$ curl -I -X POST http://admin:85703fb68927f04968630e192e4927cb@192.168.99.20:8080/job/Football/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb:44e7033af70da95a47403c3bed5c10f8"
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 02 Jun 2017 06:17:51 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://192.168.99.20:8080/queue/item/17/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

[Original link](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jnrg/running-jenkins-build-via-command-line)

In additional to the information above I've also found how to get Jenkins-Crumb with `cli` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314369/557081)

```
CRUMB=$(curl -s 'http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
```

Comment: Thanks! Using API Token was really helpful. I changed to that to let me get through moving to a Google Login Plugin. Very helpful.

Comment: Seems like the authorizationToken has been deprecated in DSL..

Comment: @DanielHajduk, Thanks. I'm not using Jenkins anymore in my projects, so cannot update my post at this moment. But I'll try to do this in nearest time.

Answer (score 8):

There’s a Jenkins plugin that works with 1.565.3 and newer which can bypass the matrix-based authentication for triggering the build job. I found this in a comment on [JENKINS-17764](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17764) (which covers this particular issue) by Emil Dragu:

Install the [Build Token Root Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin), then change the upper part in the URL to the lower equivalent (rendered as list to make it more easily visible):

- `job/`*ProjectName*`/build?token=`*test*
- `buildByToken/build?job=`*ProjectName*`&token=`*test*

You can still pass an optional `cause` argument, too.

Answer (score 3):

Agree. You can find the API token when you click on the user name which appears on right corner. Than go to configure and click on Show API Token.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this python script to submit job. This also allow to upload file to a job.

```
import os
import json
import requests
from glob import glob
from getpass import getpass

AUTH = (
    os.environ.get('JENKIN_USER') or input('Jenkin username: '),
    os.environ.get('JENKIN_PASSWORD') or getpass('Jenkin password: ')
)
TOKEN = os.environ.get('JENKIN_TOKEN') or input('Jenkin job token: ')
JENKIN_DOMAIN = 'https://jenkins'
REASON = 'Batch jenkin job'
JOB_URL = f'{JENKIN_DOMAIN}/view/some-job-url'
CRUM_ISSUER = f'{JENKIN_DOMAIN}/crumbIssuer/api/json'


session = requests.Session()

def get_crumb(auth=AUTH):
    return session.get(CRUM_ISSUER, auth=auth).json()


def build_job(job_url, params=None, files=None, token=TOKEN, cause=REASON,
              auth=AUTH):
    crum = get_crumb()
    payload = {}
    if params:
        job_url = f'{job_url}/buildWithParameters'
        parameter = []
        if files:
            for key in files:
                parameter.append({"name": key, "file": key})
        for key, value in params.items():
            parameter.append({"name": key, "value": str(value)})
        payload.update(params)
        payload['json'] = json.dumps({
            'parameter': parameter,
            'statusCode': "303",
            'redirectTo': '.'
        })
    else:
        job_url = f'{job_url}/build'

    r = session.post(
        job_url,
        data=payload,
        files=files,
        params={"token": token, "cause": cause, crum['crumbRequestField']: crum['crumb']},
        auth=auth,
        headers={crum['crumbRequestField']: crum['crumb']}
    )
    return r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Build job
    build_job(JOB_URL, params={
        'DO_SOMETHING': 'true', "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE"
    })

    # Build job with file upload
    build_job(JOB_URL, params={'NO_HEADER': 'true'}, files={'UPLOAD_FILE_FIELD': f})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same programmatically, then you can have a look at [Programmatically retrieve Jenkins REST API Token](https://medium.com/@samratshaw/programmatically-retrieve-jenkins-rest-api-token-f2c3f0d69483)

You can then use this token to authenticate the other Jenkins API's.