# Azure Flask App Services resource not passing Environment Variables

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to inject Environment Variables into an Azure "App Services" Flask resource.

*Note: I am aware that some use files to set up environment variables. I may look into that in the future, but for now I'm trying to do this without managing files.*

Per the manual, I added the environment variables as "app settings," on the portal page.

[image]

And I can see that they have been set correctly with the Azure CLI command:

```
az webapp config appsettings list --name <redacted> --resource-group <redacted>
```

which outputs:

```
{
  "name": "DB.DATABASE",
  "slotSetting": false,
  "value": "<redacted>"
},
{
  "name": "DB.DRIVER",
  "slotSetting": false,
  "value": "{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}"
},

...
```

My Python code references the variables, which works locally.

```
from os import environ


driver = environ.get('DB.DRIVER')
server = environ.get('DB.SERVER')
user_id = environ.get('DB.USER_ID')
password = environ.get('DB.PASSWORD')
database = environ.get('DB.DATABASE')
trusted_connection = environ.get('DB.TRUSTED_CONNECTION')

print(f'driver: {driver}')
print(f'server: {server}')
print(f'user_id: {user_id}')
```

and the output, in the Azure log stream is:

```
2020-10-05T17:08:01.172742838Z driver: None
2020-10-05T17:08:01.172767338Z server: None
2020-10-05T17:08:01.172772538Z user_id: None
```

What, please, am I missing from this procedure? It seemed so simple, but it just fails with no error message.

Comment: Could you try to use `__`(double underscore) instead of the `.` in your all settings?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: Thanks, Joy. That actually was the issue. I didn't see anywhere in the documentation that periods aren't allowed. If you know where that can be found, please consider putting it in an Answer, below.